# Trying to send email using Microsoft Graph using C# from behind Corporate proxy and firewall

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am writing a console application using C# that [among other things] will send an email using the Microsoft Graph Api. The code below works just fine when I am connected to an open internet connection, but fails when I am on the corporate network.

On our corporate network, all our internet traffic goes out via a proxy server which requires authentication using a valid username/password.

I'm pretty sure this proxy issue is the reason the code fails, since the https post requests would fail to get out to Microsoft's Graph servers if it is not authenticated on the proxy.

My question: How do you set up the mail sending objects to use an on-prem corporate network proxy to do https calls out to Microsoft Graph?

Here's the relevant code [extraneous code snipped and replaced with "..."]:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

...

static async Task sendEmailMessageAsync(string emailTo, string emailFrom, string subject, string body) 
{

...

string tenantId = GlobalVariables.tenantId;
string clientId = GlobalVariables.clientId;
string clientSecret = GlobalVariables.clientSecret;
string userId = GlobalVariables.userId;      
         
//The following scope is required to acquire the token
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var message = new Message
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        ContentType = BodyType.Html,
        Content = body
    },
    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
    {
        new Recipient
        {
            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
            {
                Address = emailTo
            }
        }
    }
};

IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId + "/v2.0"))
    .Build();

// Retrieve an access token for Microsoft Graph (gets a fresh token if needed).
var authResult = await confidentialClient
        .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
        .ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

var token = authResult.AccessToken;
// Build the Microsoft Graph client. As the authentication provider, set an async lambda
// which uses the MSAL client to obtain an app-only access token to Microsoft Graph,
// and inserts this access token in the Authorization header of each API request. 
GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = 
    new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
    {
        // Add the access token in the Authorization header of the API request.
        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    })
);

await graphServiceClient.Users[userId]
  .SendMail(message, false)
  .Request()
  .PostAsync();
}
```

One thing I tried was adding a clientFactory to the iConfidentialClientApplication by adding the line  ".WithHttpClientFactory(GlobalVariables.clientFactory)" thus:

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithHttpClientFactory(GlobalVariables.clientFactory)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId + "/v2.0"))
    .Build();
```

Where earlier, clientFactory was defined thus:

```
GlobalVariables.clientFactory = new ProxyEnabledHttpFactory();
```

And ProxyEnabledHttpFactory is defined thus:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
...
public class ProxyEnabledHttpFactory : IMsalHttpClientFactory
{
    public System.Net.Http.HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {
        WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(GlobalVariables.proxyUrl);
        proxy.Credentials =
            new NetworkCredential(GlobalVariables.proxyUsername,
                                  GlobalVariables.proxyPassword,
                                  GlobalVariables.proxyDomain);

        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.Proxy = proxy;            
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
        return httpClient;
    }
}
```

However, this is still generating the following error:

```
Code: generalException
Message: An error occurred sending the request.

20210311-02:30:06 ERROR ==> Stack trace:    at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendRequestAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendAsync>d__33.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at myConsoleProgram.Program.<sendEmailMessageAsync>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\Users\myUserAccount\source\repos\myConsoleProgram\myConsoleProgram\Program.cs:line 985
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the proper way to fix this issue, but I managed to get it running by adding this code to the beginning of the program so as to globally set the default proxy for all http traffic:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(GlobalVariables.proxyUrl))
{
    WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(GlobalVariables.proxyUrl);
    proxy.Credentials =
        new NetworkCredential(GlobalVariables.proxyUsername,
              GlobalVariables.proxyPassword,
              GlobalVariables.proxyDomain);
    // Set the global proxy server.
    System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = proxy;
}
```

Comment: Having written this code, I deleted the ProxyEnabledHttpFactory class and removed all code that referenced it.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, but your solution didn't work for me (.NET Core 3.1 Web API). I'll document what worked for me below.

I created a `HttpClientHandlerRetriever`:

```
internal static class HttpClientHandlerRetriever
{
    public static HttpClientHandler Execute(bool useProxy = true)
    {
        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            AllowAutoRedirect = false
        };

        if (useProxy)
        {
            httpClientHandler.UseProxy = true;
            httpClientHandler.Proxy = GetWebProxy();
            httpClientHandler.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        }

        return httpClientHandler;
    }

    private static WebProxy GetWebProxy()
    {
        return new WebProxy(host, port) // these are hardcoded since they won't change
        {
            Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        };
    }
}
```

This is used in two places. Once in the `StaticClientWithProxyFactory` (which is [based on the code found here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/HttpClient)):

```
internal class StaticClientWithProxyFactory : IMsalHttpClientFactory
{
    private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    static StaticClientWithProxyFactory()
    {
        var httpClientHandler = HttpClientHandlerRetriever.Execute();
        
        _httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
    }

    public HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {
        return _httpClient;
    }
}
```

The other place it is used is in the method `GetGraphServiceClient`:

```
    private GraphServiceClient GetGraphServiceClient(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var httpClientHandler = HttpClientHandlerRetriever.Execute(_appConfig.UseProxy.GetValueOrDefault());

        var httpProvider = new HttpProvider(httpClientHandler, true);

        return new GraphServiceClient(GetClientCredentialProvider(cancellationToken), httpProvider);
    }
```

Of course, `GetClientCredentialProvider` uses the `StaticClientWithProxyFactory`:

```
    private IAuthenticationProvider GetClientCredentialProvider(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/v2.0";

        var builder = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(ClientId)
            .WithAuthority(authority)
            .WithClientSecret(ClientSecret);

        if (_appConfig.UseProxy.GetValueOrDefault())
        {
            builder.WithHttpClientFactory(new StaticClientWithProxyFactory());
        }

        var confidentialClientApplication = builder.Build();

        return new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
            async requestMessage =>
            {
                // Retrieve an access token for Microsoft Graph (gets a fresh token if needed).
                var authenticationResult = await confidentialClientApplication
                    .AcquireTokenForClient(_scopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);

                // Add the access token in the Authorization header of the API request.
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);
            });
    }
```

Note that `_scopes` looks like this:

```
        _scopes = new List<string> { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
```

Of course you need the [Microsoft.Identity.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/) and [Microsoft.Graph](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph) packages from NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

I recently upgraded to v5 of Microsoft.Graph (my code currently uses v5.21.0), and this required some rewrites. My code uses .NET v6.0.

**MsGraphService**:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Authentication;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public abstract class MsGraphService
    {
        protected readonly MsGraphConfiguration Config;
        protected readonly ILogger Logger;

        protected GraphServiceClient GraphServiceClient;

        protected MsGraphService(MsGraphConfiguration config, ILogger logger)
        {
            Config = config;
            Logger = logger;
        }

        protected bool GraphClientToBeInitiated()
            => GraphServiceClient == null;

        protected void SetupGraphClient()
        {
            GraphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(
                    new TokenProvider(Config, Logger)));
        }
    }
}
```

**MsGraphConfiguration**:

```
public sealed class MsGraphConfiguration
{
    public bool UseProxy { get; set; }
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
    public string Secret { get; set; }
}
```

**TokenProvider**:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Authentication;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    internal sealed class TokenProvider : IAccessTokenProvider
    {
        private readonly MsGraphConfiguration _config;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public TokenProvider(MsGraphConfiguration config, ILogger logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _config = config;
        }

        public Task<string> GetAuthorizationTokenAsync(
            Uri uri,
            Dictionary<string, object> additionalAuthenticationContext = default,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var token = GetToken().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            return Task.FromResult(token);
        }

        public AllowedHostsValidator AllowedHostsValidator => throw new NotImplementedException();

        private async Task<string> GetToken()
        {
            var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{_config.TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token";

            _logger.LogInformation($"TenantId: {_config.TenantId}");
            _logger.LogInformation($"Authority: {authority}");
            _logger.LogInformation($"ClientId: {_config.ClientId}");
            _logger.LogInformation($"Secret: {_config.Secret.First()}...{_config.Secret.Last()}");

            var builder = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(_config.ClientId)
                .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
                .WithClientSecret(_config.Secret);

            if (_config.UseProxy)
                builder.WithHttpClientFactory(new StaticClientWithProxyFactory());

            var app = builder.Build();
            
            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            var authenticationResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

            _logger.LogInformation($"Authentication result: {authenticationResult.AccessToken} expires on {authenticationResult.ExpiresOn}");

            return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
        }
    }
}
```

**StaticClientWithProxyFactory**:

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    internal sealed class StaticClientWithProxyFactory : IMsalHttpClientFactory
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        static StaticClientWithProxyFactory()
        {
            var httpClientHandler = HttpClientHandlerRetriever.Execute(); // same as in my other answer to this question

            _httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("Infrabel-OpTellMe", "1.0"));
        }

        public HttpClient GetHttpClient()
        {
            return _httpClient;
        }
    }
}
```

This works for me, and I use it as the base of both a service to send emails and a service to upload files to a SharePoint site.

Answer (score -1):

update the latest version Microsoft.Graph to 3.23.0 or latest

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).